# TypeORM eager loading invalid column name with select

Tags: node.js, sql-server, typescript, typeorm

When implementing `User` entity and `Roles` entity in TypeORM, I used `@ManyToMany` with `eager` on true.

I implemented a `UserRepository` that extends `Repository`.

When using `this.find()` it works, without a problem (but also loads the password and other fields an API doesn't need to serve). When using `this.find({select: 'email firstname roles'})`, it suddenly gives me this error:

```
RequestError: Invalid column name 'userId'.
```

I also tried adding option `relations`, but that gives me error

```
QueryFailedError: Error: Invalid column name 'userId'.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Node version: 12.16.2
TypeORM version: 0.2.24
Typescript version: 3.7.4
Database: SQL Server

Role entity:

```
@Entity()
export class Role {

    @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.roles)
    @PrimaryColumn()
    role!: string
}
```

User Entity

```
@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id!: number;

    @Column()
    public email!: string;

    @Column()
    public password!: string;

    @Column()
    public firstname!: string;

    @ManyToMany(type => Role, role => role.role, {eager: true, nullable: true})
    @JoinTable()
    public roles!: Role[];
}
```

User Repository:

```
@EntityRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {

    whitelist: IWhitelist<User> = {
        admin: ['email', 'firstname','roles', 'id',]
    };

    getOptions = (list: string) => {
        return {select: this.whitelist[list], relations: ['roles']};
    };

    adminGetUsers = async (): Promise<Array<User> | undefined> => {
        return await this.find(this.getOptions('admin'));
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```js
this.find({select: ['email', 'firstname', 'roles']}
```

from the documentation :
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#basic-options